# iOS6 UIAlertView.title broken?

Tags: uialertview, title, ios6

Today's full of surprises for me... The simple code below isn't working. It never enters the block in the if statement even though the NSLog shows the title property as matching that if condition. I'm going crazy today....

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    NSLog(@"%@", alertView.title);

if (alertView.title == @"Warehouse") {
//.... never get in here even though NSLog above returns "Warehouse"
```

EDIT:
I figured it out. Answering this here in case it'll help anyone else.

Apparently iOS 6 is stricter with comparing strings or something. The == used to work fine in iOS 5 but in iOS 6 I had to use

```
if ([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Warehouse"]) {
```

then it works fine.

Comment: Thank you - wow was that annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are doing it correctly but there is a small problem -
The proper Code will be -

```
 -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:  
  (NSInteger)buttonIndex
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", alertView.title);

       if ([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"Warehouse"])

        {
          // Now it will go inside this condition
        }
   }
```

Now it will work for you.