# Text does not match text

Tags: objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iOS6 UIAlertView.title broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592377/ios6-uialertview-title-broken)

// btnstartgame.enabled = yes but it should not be enabled and I have no idea why, please help.

//PS. this code gives some saved strings to 2 labels and should then check if they are the same, though they are never the same for some reason. (they = lblTeamOne and lblTeamTwo)

```
@synthesize lblTeamOne;
@synthesize lblTeamTwo;
@synthesize sliderTeamOneOutlet;
@synthesize sliderTeamTwoOutlet;
@synthesize btnStartGame;
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self)
{
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}
-(void)loadTeams:(NSString*)location:(UILabel*)lblname
{

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *loadstring = [defaults objectForKey:location];
lblname.text = loadstring;
}
-(void)sliderdisplay:(UISlider *)sliderOutlet :(UILabel *)lblName
{

if(0 < sliderOutlet.value && 1 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save1" :lblName];

}
if(1 < sliderOutlet.value && 2 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save2" :lblName];

}
if(2 < sliderOutlet.value && 3 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save3" :lblName];

}
if(3 < sliderOutlet.value && 4 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save4" :lblName];

}
if(4 < sliderOutlet.value && 5 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save5" :lblName];

}
if(5 < sliderOutlet.value && 6 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save6" :lblName];

}
if(6 < sliderOutlet.value && 7 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save7" :lblName];

}
if(7 < sliderOutlet.value && 8 >= sliderOutlet.value)
{
    [self loadTeams:@"save8" :lblName];

}
}
-(void)loadMaximum
{

int teamAmount = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"teamAmount"] intValue];
NSNumber *yourNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:teamAmount];
float sliderMaximumDigital = [yourNumber floatValue];
[sliderTeamOneOutlet setMaximumValue:sliderMaximumDigital];
[sliderTeamTwoOutlet setMaximumValue:sliderMaximumDigital];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
[self loadMaximum];
[self loadTeams:@"save1" :lblTeamOne];
[self loadTeams:@"save1" :lblTeamTwo];


if(lblTeamOne == lblTeamTwo)
{
    btnStartGame.enabled = NO;
}
if(lblTeamOne.text == lblTeamTwo.text)
{
    btnStartGame.enabled = NO;
}
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)sliderTeamOneAction:(id)sender
{
[self sliderdisplay:sliderTeamOneOutlet :lblTeamOne];
}

- (IBAction)sliderTeamTwoAction:(id)sender
{
    [self sliderdisplay:sliderTeamTwoOutlet :lblTeamTwo];
}
```

// thank you in advance.

Comment: `if(lblTeamOne.text == lblTeamTwo.text)` - hint: you don't compare strings like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compare strings do this:

```
[string1 isEqualToString:string2]
```

If you use == you are actually comparing locations in memory (which will usually be different) rather than the content of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code Ben is right And i am giving you a link where you found your solution.Same problem was facing by another person.So you can find your solution here also -

[iOS6 UIAlertView.title broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592377/ios6-uialertview-title-broken/12619611#12619611)

Comment: Not an answer - should be a comment.